# Strange behavior with React state and initialState on radio button... [SOLVED cause is <ValidatedForm> react-jhispter failed with defaultValues]

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, state

I have a strange behavior that I can't solve using State to change Radio button.

I open my page, 'Years' is selected. It is correct. We can also see the state property in the above text field (it contains 'years');

[image: opening]

If I click on 'All', the state changes (contains 'all') BUT the RADIO button is not checked.

[image]

If I CLICK AGAIN on the same RADIO BUTTON 'All', it shows correctly :

[image]

It is like onCLick works (second time), but onCHange not.
It is like after running my onCHange function, it resets to the initial state on the page (checking the 'years' radio).

I have not clue.

Here is some part of my code (the minimum to understand) :

```
<label><input name='choix' type='radio' value='all' onChange={(e) => choixChanged(e)} checked={radioChoiceState === "all"} /> All</label>

<label><input name='choix' type='radio' value='dateRange' onChange={choixChanged} checked={radioChoiceState === "dateRange"} /> Date range</label>

<label><input name='choix' type='radio' value='years' onChange={choixChanged} checked={radioChoiceState === 'years'} /> Only years</label>

... truncated ...

const [datesRangeVisibleState, storeDatesRangeVisible] = useState(false);
const [radioChoiceState, storeRadioChoiceState] = useState('years');


const choixChanged = event => {
    const butt = event.target.value;
if (butt === 'all') {
  storeDatesRangeVisible(false);
} else if (butt === 'dateRange') {
  storeDatesRangeVisible(true);
} else {
  storeDatesRangeVisible(false);
}
storeRadioChoiceState(butt);
}
```

Please help me...

Comment: what do you mean by `It is like onCLick works (second time), but onCHange not.` is there onClick handler?

Comment: actually the state is updating correctly, could you please add us the textfield where you are rendering the output because in the console it works fine. See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bohr-juxl9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: 1. what do you mean ......
There is no onClick handler ... I meant that on the second click the radio button is correctly selected, not on first. So it is like when the state stores already the good radio button it works, but when I change the radio (onChange) button NOT.

Comment: 2. actually ....
Good idea in codesanbox .... I did not know this feature. Thanks. 
So I cannot provide the textfield like it is.. because it is <ValidatedField from react-jhister.... I tried (and save in your GitHub) with <input text> works also perfectly...
So the clue is maybe with all the other things I have in this page... I can see "useEffect(() => {" , .. "const dispatch = useAppDispatch();" ... is it the clue ?

Comment: It seems that I can not save in your code... So here is mine : https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cherry-5jbg9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: OKAY.. I finally FOUND the root cause ..
      which is the &lt;ValidatedForm> from react-jhispter that surrounds all the 3 radio buttons..
      It FAILS if I add the attribute : defaultValues=.... Why ? ....

Comment: I guess because the defulatvalues are only intially set, but I also dont know that package react-jhister... so maybe someone else can assist with that

Answer (score 0):

OKAY.. I finally FOUND the root cause .. which is the <ValidatedForm> from react-jhispter that surrounds all the 3 radio buttons.. It FAILS if I add the attribute : defaultValues=....